# How to make this "homebottom" div to have height according to "homebottomleft" div?

Tags: html, css

If you see the code, there's a div **homefront**, whose height is auto. Inside it, there's a div **homebottom**, whose height is fixed (say 400px). Inside this div, there's another div **homebottomleft**, whose height it inherit.

Now, I don't know if I've written the right code or not, for what I need.

I need then as soon as the height of **homebottomleft** increases, the **homebottom** div's height should also increase with it, automatically. It's not working even though I've tried some CSS properties. Please help if you can.

```
<div class="homefront">
    <div class="homebottom">
      <div class="homebottomleft"><br>
         <div class="profile_pic"><?php echo '<img src="' . $headerImage . '" height="173" width="173"/>'; ?></div>
          <div class="profilename"><?php echo $profilename; ?></div><hr>
          <h3 id="groups">CONTACTS</h3>
          <h4 id="links">
          <br><br><br><br>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="homebottomright">
        <div class="homebottomright_status">
        <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:700; margin: 0px;">UPDATE STATUS</p>
        <form name="statusform" method="post" action="">
        <textarea style="overflow: hidden; resize: none;" class="statusbox" placeholder="Share something new..." name="status"></textarea><br>
        <input class="postbutton" type="submit" name="updatestatus" value="POST"/>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="homebottomright_updates">
        Something
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.homefront{
width:1020px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 15px;
}

.homebottom{
width: inherit;
height: auto;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0.5px grey;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.homebottomleft{
    width: 175px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
        background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0.5px grey;

    position: relative;
}
.homebottomright{
width: 800px;
height: auto;
float: right;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "even though I've tried some CSS properties"? What properties? Post the CSS code too, please. Or better, make a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: try `height: auto` and `min-height: 400px` on `.homebottom`. If that doesn't work, can you post your css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which method of ‘clearfix’ is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: I solved it using "overflow: hidden" :)